# Cleaning vinyl siding that is hard to reach and has cobwebs

Tags: vinyl-siding

My siding is in a corner and high and hard to reach.  It also ha cobwebs that do not clean wih a power washer.  How do I clean this?

Comment: How high is high?  A brush on a long pole should do it, or you will need to raise yourself up more with a ladder or a man lift.

Comment: Provide a photo, better include the view on the "cobwebs".

Comment: cobwebs that withstand a power washer? ... that must be a hell of a spider

Comment: Cobwebs on the outside of the house, in a place that is high up and hard to reach from the ground are a problem? Oh, yeah, if you're a fly or a mosquito...

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.